# Running Odoo Enterprise Studio from code (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, github, odoo-10

Where is the Odoo Studio code? Is it part of the Odoo Enterprise code on Github (which I have access to)?

Is there something I need to enable or add to the project so I see the Studio?
Currently when I run the Odoo Community code, (with the addons path in odoo.conf set correctly first to the enterprise directory) I see no Studio option in the header.

So two questions:

1. Where is the Studio code and how do I access it?
2. What do I need to do so I see it, when running the Odoo code from Eclipse?

Comment: Please have a look inside given answer and do not hesitate to ask anything which is not clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Studio code is the one of the module inside the Odoo Enterprise addons with named "web_studio". For that you need the access of the Enterprise addons.

2) After installing the module web_studio you can get the one icon on top right corner before logged in user name like tools with tool tip "Customization". By clicking on that you can start the Studio for manage any changes inside the current screen.

I hope you are getting both of the answer correct fully.

Comment: Yes I saw web_studio. But how do I "install the module" web studio. I added the enterprise path  to the add_ons path as instructed, but when I open the Odoo Apps in localhost I see only the community modules. A search for Web Studio or Studio results in no modules found.

Comment: It turned out I had the wrong path.
I simply closed github desktop and eclipse, moved the Enterprise directory under odoo. Opened Github desktop and pressed "locate" and connected it. Then I opened eclipse, changed the addons path in my conf file to simply: enterprise, ...  Then pressed Activate Developers Mode, Modules->update module list, found the web_studio and installed it. Alls ok that ends ok.